# Merging cells in a table doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, html-table

This is a table that I would like to achieve:

[image: correctly rendered table]

But I keep getting something like this:

[image: rendered table with error]

This is what I've tried:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td colspan="2">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">d</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a link to JSFiddle with this (with some extra code for illustration): http://jsfiddle.net/2292D/

Comment: Your JSFiddle  is not similar to what you said you get on your post it's normal?

Comment: Is this you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/NSJxE/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good old days using `table`, use [`rowspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan) and [`colspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/td/colspan) to achieve that kind of tablular structure, if you are using this for layout than don't, use `div` instead with `float` and CSS Positioning.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dandg/)

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" width="30%">a</td>
        <td colspan="2">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="70%">d</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only `vertical-align:middle` and `text-align:center`

Apply this css to div

```
div {
   display:table-cell; // Change
   vertical-align:middle; //Change
   border: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
    border:  1px solid red;
    text-align:center; // Change

}
```

[**<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/2292D/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need 3 rows for that, try my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><div id="a">a</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="b">b</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>       
    <td colspan="2"><div id="c">c</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="d">d</div></td>
    <td><div id="e">e</div></td>
</tr>
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLe5c/

Answer (score 0):

apply your id on td

```
html:

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td  id="a" rowspan="2"><div>a</div></td>
            <td id="b" colspan="2"><div >b</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c" colspan="2"><div >c</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="d" colspan="2"><div >d</div></td>
            <td id="e"><div >e</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">a</td>
    <td colspan="2">b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="2">d</td>
    <td>e</td>
</tr>
</table>

<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    border:  1px solid red;
}

</style>
```